# Using sqlcipher in TypeScript

Tags: cordova, typescript, sqlcipher

I'm creating Cordova app with TypeScript.

Does anyone know how to use sqlcipher in TypeScript?

I found this very useful extension but I want to use it in TypeScript.
Is it possible? or Any other good solutions?

https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter

Comment: Too late to ask, but did you find a solution or tutorial? The below solution does not work for me. I am trying to use this in ionic 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to use sqlcipher in TypeScript

Your JavaScript is TypeScript. The library : https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlcipher-adapter exposes a varaible `sqlitePlugin`. You can use it with TypeScript very easily:

```
declare var sqlitePlugin:any;
```

And you will be in no way more worse off than just JavaScript.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/migrating.html